# cordova purchase finish() not fired

Tags: android, cordova, in-app-purchase

I am using the latest version of the cordova purchase plugin (by j3k0).

I have a problem, the finish() even never gets called. But Only on Android.

Does anyone have this problem too? I must add that the pop up to pay is called, I can make the payment, and I get an 'Ok' answer. So it must mean the purchase was saved, but the finished() event never fires.

Thank you for your help!

This is my code.

```
  this.CdvPurchase.store
            .when()
            .productUpdated(product => {
                this.logObjet('when productUpdated:product', product);
            })
            .approved(transaction => {
                this.logObjet('when approved:transaction', transaction);

         
                transaction.finish();
                const produitVerification = this.CdvPurchase.store.get(this.valeurEnvoi.app, plateformeStore);
                const transactionVerification = this.CdvPurchase.store.findInLocalReceipts(produitVerification);
                this.logObjet('when approved:produitVerification', produitVerification);
                this.logObjet('when approved:transactionVerification', transactionVerification);

                // transaction.verify();
            })
            .verified(receipt => {
                 this.logObjet('when verified:receipt', receipt);
                 receipt.finish();
                 // this.enregistrerPaiementMobile(informationsTransaction);
             }).finished(receipt => {
                this.logObjet('when finished:receipt', receipt);
                const produitVerification = this.CdvPurchase.store.get(this.valeurEnvoi.app, plateformeStore);
                const transactionVerification = this.CdvPurchase.store.findInLocalReceipts(produitVerification);
                this.logObjet('when finished:produitVerification', produitVerification);
                this.logObjet('when finished:transactionVerification', transactionVerification);
                // this.enregistrerPaiementMobile(informationsTransaction);
            });

        this.CdvPurchase.store.register([
            {
                id: this.valeurEnvoi.app,
                platform: plateformeStore,
                type: typeProduit,
            },
        ]);

        this.CdvPurchase.store.ready(() => {
            const produit = this.CdvPurchase.store.get(this.valeurEnvoi.app, plateformeStore);

            this.logObjet('when ready:store.get:produit', produit, 'offers');

            if (produit.canPurchase) {
                this.CdvPurchase.store.order(produit.getOffer());
            }

        });

        this.CdvPurchase.store.initialize([
            plateformeStore,
        ]);
```